# Trying to load a gif image but does not load in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to load a gif image on a button click but it doesn't work on chrome, works fine in others. It works if I load a png image but I need animation for loading.

code used:

```
function showModalandLoadingAni(){
    $('#shadeSearchLoading').show();
    $('#modalSearchLoading').show();
    $('#modalSearchLoading').html('<div class="loading-big-img" style="z-index:99999; top:65px;"></div>');
}
```

I have tried loading the image in `$(document).ready`.. but no luck..

Relevant CSS (from a comment):

```
.loading-big-img {
    display:block; 
    background: #FFF url('../images/custom/loading_big.gif') no-repeat center center; 
    float:left; 
    width:106px; 
    height:106px; 
    position: absolute; 
    top:185px; 
    left: 385px;
}
```

Comment: Does a simplistic `<img src="my.gif">` work for you in Chrome? Also, what is your Chrome version?

Comment: yes i tried that it doesn't work i am using version 17 the latest one

Comment: Does it not display or does it display but not animate?

Comment: it does not display anything at all..works fine for png..

Comment: Do other anigifs work for you? I can't believe animated gifs are broken for all Chrome users. You may just have some non-standard/broken GIF format.

Comment: it works in all other browser.. prob occurs only with chrome..

Comment: It works for me in Chrome with a random animated gif: http://jsfiddle.net/LS4kQ/

Comment: i had tried it in jsfiddles.. it works fine in that but not in my porject..

Comment: Did you try jsfiddle with your anigif in question? If it works for you, you may just have your path in CSS confused.

Comment: @lee we can't help you if you won't provide more HTML/JS/CSS code..

Comment: Thanx a lot everyone.. i solved it.. actually the gif image was not loading properly, putting it in onload did the job...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `position:absolute` for the div css. How do you add the image, via background-image in css?

Comment: .loading-big-img
{
 display:block;
 background: #FFF url('../images/custom/loading_big.gif') no-repeat center center;
 float:left;
 width:106px;
 height:106px;
 position: absolute;
 top:185px;
 left: 385px;
}             the class has been styled as above...

Comment: Added that CSS into the question in a more readable format, since it may be relevant.

Comment: yes it does and on clicking the image link.. the image shows up in a new tab.